# _.pluck gives an array of undefined values when it does not find the object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm using _.pluck() from lodash to get the value of the keys from an array.

```
var employees = [
  {
    Name : "abc"  
  },
  {
    Name : "xyz"
  }
]

var res = _.pluck(employees, 'Name');
```

Variable res would contain ['abc,'xyz']

When I do a search for some other field field

```
var res = _.pluck(employees, 'SomeRandomField');
```

Result  - [undefined, undefined]

How can I get the above result just as null of undefined instead of an array
of undefined values

Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/qtmm6xgdReCuJP5fm1P2?p=preview

Comment: `just as null of undefined` -> What do you mean by that?

Comment: i've updated with a plnkr when you run it in console you'll see [undefined,undefined]

Comment: What do you want the expected output to be?

Comment: null or just undefined instead of it being in an array

Comment: What if only one object doesn't have `SomeRandomField` and all others have that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like you're actually looking for the [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function:

```
var res = _.pluck(employees, "Name");
res = res.some(function (d) { return d }) ? // are any of the elements truth-y?
    // if so, map the  false-y items to null
    res.map(function (item) { return item || null; }) :
    // otherwise (no truth-y items) make res `null`
    null;
```

---

I took a look at the lodash documentation for [`.pluck`](https://lodash.com/docs#pluck) and I don't believe that's possible.

> `_.pluck(collection, key)`
>
> Arguments
>   collection *(Array|Object|string)*: The collection to iterate over.
>
> key (string): The key of the property to pluck.

What you can instead do is `.pluck` then use JavaScript's builtin (or lodash's) `.map`:

```
var res = _.pluck(employees, 'Name').map(function (d) {
    return d ? d : null;
});
```

Which is rather inefficient. You might as well write your own function that only iterates over the array once:

```
_.nullPluck = function (arr, key) {
    return arr.map(function (d) {
        return d && d[key] ? d[key] : null;
    }) 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `filter` and `pluck`:

```
var res = _.filter(_.pluck(employees, 'Name'), function(item) {
    return item;
});
```

Comment: the default `_.filter` predicate is simply `_.identity` so you don't need a predicate in this case.  And if you wanted to discard empty strings (which are treated as falsey) as well then `_.compact` might be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [compact()](https://lodash.com/docs#compact) to remove *falsey* values from the plucked array. You can use [thru()](https://lodash.com/docs#thru) to alter the output of the wrapper. In this case, we want `null` if all the plucked values are `undefined`.

```
var collection = [ {}, {}, {} ];

_(collection)
    .pluck('foo')
    .compact()
    .thru(function(coll) { return _.isEmpty(coll) ? null : coll; })
    .value();
// → null
```